converting pem file to encrypted private key file of PBES1 format in Python
I am writing a program where I am trying to convert the certs, which is of pem format into PBES1 private key (the one with -----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY----- and -----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY----- header and footer.)
Below is the code I wrote. I am specific about the encryption algorithm used here for compatibility reasons. I was initially trying to use utf-8 encoding, but it gave me
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode »(,¾æ0x82 in position 1: invalid start byte

hence I changed it to latin-1, but please correct me if I am wrong here.
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import PrivateFormat, pkcs12
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend


def get_CN(crt_subject: x509.Name) -> str:
    return next(attr.value for attr in crt_subject if attr.oid == x509.NameOID.COMMON_NAME)


def pkcs12_pbes1(password: str, pkey, clcert, cacerts: list[x509.Certificate]) -> bytes:
    encryption_algorithm = (
        PrivateFormat.PKCS12.encryption_builder()
        .kdf_rounds(30)
        .key_cert_algorithm(pkcs12.PBES.PBESv1SHA1And3KeyTripleDESCBC)
        .hmac_hash(hashes.SHA256())
        .build(password.encode("latin-1"))
        )

    return pkcs12.serialize_key_and_certificates(
        name=get_CN(clcert.subject).encode("latin-1"),
        key=pkey,
        cert=clcert,
        cas=cacerts,
        encryption_algorithm=encryption_algorithm,
    )


def load_ec_private_key_from_pem(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as pem_file:
            pem_data = pem_file.read()
        private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
            pem_data,
            password=None,  # Assuming the private key is not password-protected
            backend=default_backend()
        )
        return private_key
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", e)
        return None


def read_pem_file(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as pem_file:
            pem_data = pem_file.read()
        p_cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(pem_data)
        return p_cert
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"Error: File '{file_path}' not found.")
        return None
    

p_cert = read_pem_file('test_cert.pem')
p_key = load_ec_private_key_from_pem('test_key.pem')
p_ca = read_pem_file('test_ca.pem')

pbes1_pem = pkcs12_pbes1("somepasswd", p_key, p_cert, [p_ca])
print(pbes1_pem.decode('latin-1'))


Upon testing, I am able to read my test cert, key and ca from the file and the pbes1_pem seems to be a binary array in encrypted form. However, I fail to write it to another file of encrypted private key pem format like below
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
data
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----


I was going through the hazmat documentation and I couldn't find a helper function that could convert the encrypted binary array into the above mentioned specified format. Is this the part where I need to base64 encode the data myself and add it within those header and footer manually, or is there a helper function that I'm missing? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY----- is used to signal that the file is an encrypted PKCS8 private key file. It should not be used for a pkcs12 file. I've not seen PEM-style PKCS12 files in the wild, nor have I seen software that generates them or accepts them, so I don't know why you are trying to generate them. As for the specific error, PKCS12 files are binary files that make no sense as character strings and contain illegal byte sequences when interpreted by various character decoders. It won't throw an error with latin-1, but the output makes no sense.

Thank you @PresidentJamesK.Polk. Is it acceptable to write this as a binary file into the disk as it is and let whatever program to load it as the binary file itself? If so, what would that file be conventionally? A .p12 file? I am coming from a place where historically, the file on disk is of -----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY----- format (.pem), which is later loaded into  keystore by keytool, which is read by a java client application.

I don't understand the consuming application. Java's keytool can't read PKCS8 files at all, and it can't read PKCS12 files unless they're in their standard binary format.
